# Save current date and user Input to Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a note-saving app using Firebase Firestore and a RecyclerView.

So far users are able to enter the title and content of the note, this saves and works fine.

What I would like to add is the current date (in a "dd/MM/yy" format) when the user saves the note to be displayed in the recycler view the notes are displayed in.

My code for adding the note is as follows

```
public class AddWellbeingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "AddWellbeingActivity";
EditText createtitleofnote, createcontentofnote;
FloatingActionButton savenote;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_wellbeing);

    savenote = findViewById(R.id.saveNote);
    createcontentofnote = findViewById(R.id.createContentNote);
    createtitleofnote = findViewById(R.id.createTitleNote);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    

    savenote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = createtitleofnote.getText().toString();
            String content = createcontentofnote.getText().toString();


            if(title.isEmpty() || content.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Both fields are Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("notes").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).collection("myNotes").document();
                Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
                note.put("title",title);
                note.put("content", content);

                documentReference.set(note).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wellbeing entry saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(AddWellbeingActivity.this, WellbeingActivity.class));

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wellbeing entry failed to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone has a solution it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To add a timestamp field when add a note into Firestore, then you should add an extra `put()` call:

```
note.put("title",title);
note.put("content", content);
note.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

Comment: Hey. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?